# Android auto run app if "Unfortunaty app has stopped"

Tags: android

I have app which sometimes gives me error "Unfortunately app has stopped". Is it possible to make receiver or something what would run my app if it stopped unfortunately with this error? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good idea to avoid application crash and restart application, however, you can achieve this by making a uncaught exception handler.

Create one activity like this.

```
 public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
               android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
               Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.setPackage(<Your Application Package>);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
     }
 }
```

Now Extend all your activities with this class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using method `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";
    private static final String KEY_APP_CRASHED = "KEY_APP_CRASHED";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
                // Save the fact we crashed out.
                getSharedPreferences( TAG , Context.MODE_PRIVATE ).edit()
                    .putBoolean( KEY_APP_CRASHED, true ).apply();
                // Chain default exception handler.
                if ( defaultHandler != null ) {
                    defaultHandler.uncaughtException( thread, exception );
                }
            }
        } );

        boolean bRestartAfterCrash = getSharedPreferences( TAG , Context.MODE_PRIVATE )
                .getBoolean( KEY_APP_CRASHED, false );
        if ( bRestartAfterCrash ) {
            // Clear crash flag.
            getSharedPreferences( TAG , Context.MODE_PRIVATE ).edit()
                .putBoolean( KEY_APP_CRASHED, false ).apply();
            // Re-launch from root activity with cleared stack.
            Intent intent = new Intent( this, MyRootActivity.class );
            intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            startActivity( intent );
        }
    }
}
```